# Best practice for show data in all pages

Tags: symfony, twig

In terms of performance and best practices. If I most show a list of recent blog posts in all pages, what would be the best solution?.

1. Create a twig extension function `lastPosts()` that return the list (maybe through a service) and iterate over it.
2. Use twig `{% render %}` tag for call `lastPostsAction()` in PostController.

Do you prefer others alternative?

Comment: you can improve 1. by putting the call and the iteration in a seperate view and then use {% include everywhere you want to show it

Comment: Thanks @john, yes I'll probably do it. But in my situation, I don't need that because the call is inside the base layout.twig.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use `render` and set up a function in your `PostController` you can add caching which would boost your performance. Consider the following:

***services.yml***

```
services:
    foo.posts_cache:
       class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\PhpFileCache
       arguments: [%kernel.cache_dir%/posts]
```

***PostController***

```
$cache = $this->get('foo.posts_cache');
// you can differentiate your cache id based on locale or pageId, route, etc.
$cacheid = 'posts'; 

if( null == ( $posts = $cache->fetch( $cacheid ) ) )
{
     //fetch your posts
     $posts = array();

     // then save them for a day
     $cache->save( $cacheid , $posts , 86400 );
}

return $posts;
```

Check out the full documentation here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html

Please bear in mind that using render in your templates *should be limited* as this issues sub-requests and in some cases are hard to debug.